# Test convert string to date time other than DateTime.TryParseExact

Tags: c#, string, datetime, typeconverter, tryparse

Good day,

Normally, If I want to test whether a string is a valid date time format, I will use :

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact()){
//do something
}
```

I would like to ask, is there any code can direct test Convert.ToDateTime() is successful or not?
For example like :

```
if (Convert.ToDateTime(date1)){
//do something
}
```

or

```
if(Convert.ToDateTime(date1) == true){
//do soemthing
}
```

My idea is make it become bool to test it successful convert to date time or not.
Just trying to find out the code instead of using DateTime.TryParseExact()

Comment: What's wrong with DateTime.TryParseExact?

Comment: Wrap your code with `try..catch`

Comment: Any particular reason not to use `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`? That's exactly what they are there for.

Comment: @Darren, There is nothing worng with `DateTime.TryParseExact` ,
I am just thinking is there any way like what I think or not. 
@Corak, Because if use `DateTime.TryParse`, I need to declare a format to check, sometimes the date time format maybe different, thats why I am thinking is there any code like what I think.

Comment: Well, you can always wrap it in a little method yourself, which handles the declaration of the `out` object but doesn't do anything with it. And since there are about two bazillion different ways to represent a `DateTime` as a string, it's in your own interest to restrict exactly which formats you accept. There are ongoing wars between `dd/MM` and `MM/dd`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first code

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact()) {
    //do something
}
```

does exactly what you want.

Use it like this:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, ...)) {    // OR use DateTime.TryParse()
    // str is a valid DateTime
}
else {
    // str is not valid
}
```

You may use `DateTime.TryParse()` if you don't want to provide a format.
Both methods returns a `bool`ean value.

Comment: I understand what you means. If using `DateTime.TryParseExact(str, format, ...)` , I need to declare a format to check.

My question is, can I transfer the `Convert.ToDateTime(str)` become bool or not.

Comment: @PanadolChong: As mentioned, you can also use `DateTime.TryParse()`, where you don't have to provide a format.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to you can use convert to. However using this means you do not get the features that tryparse can give you.

**TryParse:**

-Simple if/else validation

-Wont crash and burn your app if bad data is put into it

```
public static bool
{ 
    TryParse(string s, out DateTime result)
}
```

Then if else validation

**ConvertTo:**

-If bad data is put in, your app will crash

-Better to include a try catch into this

-See the [msdn article on ConvertTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert.ToDateTime.aspx)

```
 private static void ConvertToDateTime(string value)
 {
  DateTime convertedDate;
  try {
     convertedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
     Console.WriteLine("'{0}' converts to {1} {2} time.", 
                       value, convertedDate, 
                       convertedDate.Kind.ToString());
  }
  catch (FormatException) {
     Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in the proper format.", value);
  }
}
```

In my eyes you should always preference to Tryparse.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments:

> I need to declare a format to check, sometimes the date time format maybe different, thats why I am thinking is there any code like what I think.

`TryParseExact` already takes a format.

This short example does what you want using [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx). `TryParseExact` won't throw an exception if the format or date is wrong so you don't have to worry about expensive `Try/Catch` blocks. Instead it will return `false`.

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.Write(ValidateDate("ddd dd MMM h:mm tt yyyy", "Wed 10 Jul 9:30 AM 2013"));
    Console.Read();
}

public static bool ValidateDate(string date, string format)
{
   DateTime dateTime;
   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
   {
       Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Invalid date or format");
       return false;
   }
}
```

Or shortened:

```
public static bool ValidateDate(string date, string format)
{
    DateTime dateTime;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Then use something like this.

```
bool isDateTimeValid(string date, string format)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime outDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `DateTime.TryParseExact(...)` does not throw a exception. Did you mean `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Comment: Edited, yes I wanted to use ParseExact

Comment: @joe - actually, there is a bit more "magic" behind `TryParse/TryParseExact`, mainly, that it *doesn't* use any `try ... catch`. And because catching an exception is really slow, one should always prefer using `TryParse/TryParseExact`.